# Multi language in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

What is the approach that let me localize the SharePoint with multiple language!

I read about variations but it is not reflected on the custom web parts!

Addition to I need to browse any page and when click on the language icon I would love to localize the same page and never go back to the home page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint, variation and MUI just work for the system labels, not for the custom web parts.
For the custom web parts, you can define the localized values for them.

[Localize SharePoint Framework client-side web parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/localize-web-parts#localize-the-web-part-manifest)